# What is the exact effect of the context menu "Print" in Windows and how to parametrize it?

Tags: windows

The contextual menu appearing after right-clicking a file or a group of file often display "Print" as an option.

I wanted to know the exact effect of clicking on the button. Trying it on a bunch of pdf file, it seems to open them in Adobe Reader, start the print options (with default setting I guess) and close them. Only is left the empty Adobe Reader interface after printing. Is it the only effect, that is:

1. Open the file (with the default program?)
2. Start printing
3. Close the file

More interestingly to me, is there a way to parametrize the effects of the "Print" option of the contextual menu?

For example,

1. keep the file open after printing
2. use a specific program (different from the left-click default program)
3. etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Print" command in the context menu seems to do a couple of things.
Obviously only Microsoft could answer you in every detail, but this is my experience:

- It opens the file in it's predefined default application and performs the euquivalent of pressing <kbd>CTRL+P</kbd>
- Now it depends on how the application executes <kbd>CTRL+P</kbd>. Most Apps show the default printing dialog, like you have noticed Adobe Reader or also JPG pictures and the Windows Picture Viewer. But some applications do have a Quick Print mapped to the shortcut <kbd>CTRL+P</kbd>, like MS Word or Excel. These apps bypass the printing dialog and just print with the default settings using the below method:
- Get the computer's [default printer from the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311201/get-default-printer-name-from-command-line) under *"C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs"* ***1)***
- Execute the "[print](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772773%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) /d:DefaultPrinterFromPreviousScript PATH" command which activates the [Windows Spooler Service spoolsv.exe](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20spooler%20service&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=Li8FVvH8I4TXUafmg4AK#newwindow=1&q=windows%20spooler%20service%20), which controls the PC's printing queue.

> ***1)*** Proof that this script is used by the system: Get owner rights on
>   that file, rename it and try to print for instance a JPG from the
>   context menu. The default App opens only to display a fatal internal
>   error. Don't forget to rename it back to what it was!

To your other question. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find any information about modifying the "Print" Context Menu Handler. Not from the registry, nor from settings.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer, you can edit the context menu's `print` command this way:

Open registry editor (Win+R->Regedit) then navigate for example to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt`. Look at the right panel and you'll see `Default` value is `txtfile` or similar.

Go back to the left panel to find `txtfile` key below in the classes root branch (focus the tree and start typing `txt`), it'll scroll down to  `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile`.

Check the default value for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\print\command` in the right panel.
Mine is `%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE /p %1`. Look at that `/p`.
You can edit here whatever you want.

Consider `.txt` key entry as the point where that file extension receives a type or name. Then the actions are defined below for that type. This way, more than one file extension could point to the same actions.

I used `.txt` example because all of its keys are easier to follow. Perhaps  `.pdf` will be a little messier (I don't use Adobe Reader).

pd: feel free to edit my bad english/composition.